# I want to freeze a model to change the API from Python to C++

Tags: python, tensorflow

frozen_graph = freeze_session(sess,output_names=[out.op.name for out in model.outputs])

this error appears:
Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `op`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
how should I change that.

Comment: convert a frozen graph from current keras implementation should be avoided. Please provide more information on Keras version, Tf version and your model

Comment: I have changed the keras version to v1
sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()

My model is an ANN and tg version is 2.9.1